# How to convert hex characters when using Postgres COPY FROM?

Tags: postgresql, sybase, postgresql-copy

I am importing data from a file to PostgreSQL database table using `COPY FROM`.
Some of the strings in my file contain hex characters (mostly \x0d and \x0a) and I'd like them to be converted into *regular text* using `COPY`.
**My problem** is that they are treated as *regular text* and remain in the string unchanged.
How can I get the hex values converted?

Here is a simplified example of my situation:

```
-- The table I am importing to
CREATE TABLE my_pg_table (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    value text
);

COPY my_pg_table(id, data)
FROM 'location/data.file'
WITH CSV
DELIMITER '    ' -- this is actually a tab
QUOTE ''''
ENCODING 'UTF-8'
```

Example file:

```
1    'some data'  
2    'some more data \x0d'  
3    'even more data \x0d\x0a'
```

Note: the file is tab delimited.

Now, doing:

```
SELECT * FROM my_pg_table
```

would get me results containing hex.

**Additional info for context:**

My task is to export data from sybase tables (many hundreds) and import to Postgres. I am using `UNLOAD` to export data to files like so:

```
UNLOAD
TABLE my_sybase_table
TO 'location/data.file'
DELIMITED BY '    ' -- this is actually a tab
BYTE ORDER MARK OFF
ENCODING 'UTF-8'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that (for a reason I don't understand) hex is only converted when using `FORMAT TEXT` and `FORMAT CSV` will treat it as *regular* string.

**Solving the problem in my situation:**
Because I had to use `TEXT` I didn't have the `QUOTE` option anymore and because of that I couldn't have quoted strings in my files anymore. So I needed my files in a little different format and eventually used this to export my table from sybase:

```
UNLOAD
    SELECT
    COALESCE(cast(id as long varchar), '(NULL)'),
    COALESCE(cast(data as long varchar), '(NULL)')
    FROM my_sybase_table
TO 'location/data.file'
DELIMITED BY '    ' -- still tab delimited
BYTE ORDER MARK OFF
QUOTES OFF
ENCODING 'UTF-8'
```

and to import it to postgres:

```
COPY my_pg_table(id, data)
FROM 'location/data.file'
DELIMITER '    ' -- tab delimited
NULL '(NULL)'
ENCODING 'UTF-8'
```

I used (NULL), because I needed a way to differentiate between an empty string and `null`. I casted every column to long varchar, to make my mass export/import more convenient.

I'd be still very interested to know why hex wouldn't convert when using `FORMAT CSV`.

Comment: The answer to the question in your last paragraph: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html section File Formats: "backslash is not a special character in the CSV format"